# gcc list node swap implementation overcomplicated?

Tags: c++, list, gcc

I'm using the SGI STL (GCC) as a reference for a custom library, and while digging into `std::list::swap()` came across the following implementation,

**Note:** This method does not handle adjacent nodes properly.

```c++
// namespace std {
// namespace __detail {
void
_List_node_base::swap(_List_node_base& __x, _List_node_base& __y) throw()
{
  if ( __x._M_next != &__x )
    {
      if ( __y._M_next != &__y )
        {
          // Both __x and __y are not empty.
          std::swap(__x._M_next,__y._M_next);
          std::swap(__x._M_prev,__y._M_prev);
          __x._M_next->_M_prev = __x._M_prev->_M_next = &__x;
          __y._M_next->_M_prev = __y._M_prev->_M_next = &__y;
        }
      else
        {
          // __x is not empty, __y is empty.
          __y._M_next = __x._M_next;
          __y._M_prev = __x._M_prev;
          __y._M_next->_M_prev = __y._M_prev->_M_next = &__y;
          __x._M_next = __x._M_prev = &__x;
        }
    }
  else if ( __y._M_next != &__y )
    {
      // __x is empty, __y is not empty.
      __x._M_next = __y._M_next;
      __x._M_prev = __y._M_prev;
      __x._M_next->_M_prev = __x._M_prev->_M_next = &__x;
      __y._M_next = __y._M_prev = &__y;
    }
}
```

This looks to me as if it could be simplified to,

```
void
_List_node_base::swap(_List_node_base& __x, _List_node_base& __y) throw()
{
  _List_node_base* __xnext = __x._M_next;
  _List_node_base* __xprev = __x._M_prev;
  _List_node_base* __ynext = __y._M_next;
  _List_node_base* __yprev = __y._M_prev;

  __xnext->_M_prev = __xprev->_M_next = &__y;
  __ynext->_M_prev = __yprev->_M_next = &__x;
  std::swap(__x._M_next,__y._M_next);
  std::swap(__x._M_prev,__y._M_prev);
}
```

I've tested this for all cases (empty/empty, empty/not-empty, etc.), including `__x` and `__y` referencing the same node, and it *seems* to work, however, my trust in the SGI codebase is making me doubt myself.

So my question is: Is this correct? And if so is there any benefit to using the longer version?

Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like it is doing extra checks for some reason. I don't see how the original is better than your simplified version.

Comment: I am not sure, but check to see edge cases where one is a predecessor of the other.

Comment: @Ami Tavory The arguments to this method are always list heads, so I hadn't even considered that this may have been written to be general purpose. It's a non-issue for my purposes, but definitely worth checking.

Comment: After some testing, neither method works properly for the suggested cases.

Comment: Gcc welcomes improvements, if you are willing to contribute... The current version is long but trivial to understand. Your version would require a nice comment (and testcase if there isn't one already) to go with it.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I plan to contribute when I have something substantial, but given the work and time it takes to get a patch committed to Gcc, a change that does little more than improve code density, doesn't seem worthwhile.

Comment: Removing 2 tests could also have a measurable speed impact. In your version, I believe that you should avoid having two `=` on the same line: one `_M_next` is modified, one `_M_next` is read, and it isn't clear if they can be the same and what the consequences are.

Comment: @MarcGlisse This is only a problem when `__x` and `__y` are adjacent. Taking a nod from the Gcc version, this method is not required/expected to work correctly for adjacent nodes, so I never worried about it... But you are absolutely right - by taking temporaries, this should work for all cases!

Answer (score 2):

Self-assignment checks were all the rage. They're known to be pessimizations and bug-hiding now. You may want to find a more modern source of inspiration.

Comment: I don't think those are self-assignment checks, pretty sure they're checks for sequence empty in a circular list. Do you have any suggestions for a modern source?